# how to call ajax request everytime button is click on pagination js

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

i have a module where i display my data as a list by using pagination js plugin

here is my current script: but with this script it load all the data from my datatabase.

```
   var dataContainer = $('.latest_articles')
        $('#pagenation').pagination({
            dataSource: function(done) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: '/api/dropdownModuleFiles/getall/'+id,
                    dataType:'JSON',
                     beforeSend: function() {
                        dataContainer.html('Loading data ...');
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        done(response);
                    }
                });
            },
            locator: 'items',

            totalNumberLocator: function(response) {
                // you can return totalNumber by analyzing response content
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 100)) + 100;
            },
            pageSize: 10,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            callback: function(data, pagination) {

                 var html = simpleTemplate(data);
                 dataContainer.html(html);
            }
        })


     function simpleTemplate(data) {

            var fileHtml = '<article class="grid_post" id="article_files">';

            $.each(data, function(index, item){
                var ext = (item.dropdownFileUrl).split('.').pop();
                if(ext == 'pdf'){
                    fileHtml+='<figure>'+
                        '<figcaption>'+

                            '<h4 class="grid_post_title">'+item.dropdownFileTitle+'</h4>'+
                            '<div class="element-block">'+
                                '<a target="_blank" href="'+item.dropdownFileUrl+'" class="btn link-btn btn-outline btn-rounded">Click here &#8702;</a>'+
                            '</div>'+
                        '</figcaption>'+
                    '</figure>';  
                }
            });
              fileHtml += '</article>';
            return fileHtml;
        }
```

since it loads all data from my database pagination looks like this.

```
<<  1 2 3 4 ..... 10 >>
```

but when i limit the query to 10 pagination will only look like this

```
<< 1 >>
```

it affects the pagination based on my query. what i wanted to achieve is to display the first 10 data but pagination will display based on how many data to load. then when i click the next/prev button or the number it will call ajax request to load the next/prev 10

Comment: Hi there, anychance did you find a solution?